# Why isn't Beautiful Soup finding page element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urlopen

Bs4 noobie here. Tried more than a few methods to get this to work but now I'm straight up confused.

In trying to parse this page: https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/NYK/2021.html

I am looking for a specific table using the below code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

year = 2021
team = "NYK"
team_url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{team}/{year}.html"
html = urlopen(team_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tbl = soup.find('table', {'id': 'team_misc'})
print(tbl)
```

My output is an empty list `[]`

When I inspect the page, the table with an id team_misc exists. I'm looking at it with my own eyes. Yet my code returns nothing. Any obvious reason why? I won't list everything I've tried due to time, but if a suggestion is brought up, I'll say whether I tried it or not.

Thanks again!

Comment: `id="team_misc"` is inside a commented block.

Comment: The table that you see in the inspector is added dynamically with JavaScript. BS doesn't run JS.

Comment: BeautifulSoup can only see whatever is baked into the HTML at the time the server served it to you. It cannot see content which is populated into the DOM via JavaScript asynchronously, which is what would normally happen if you view this page like it's meant to be seen - in a real browser. It looks like, however, that the data you're trying to scrape is indeed baked into the HTML, it's just not baked into a table. It seems to be sort of scattered all over the place, sometimes in comments I think. You'll have to parse the HTML manually.

Comment: Got it, so it appears like it's inside a real code block, when in reality, its added into the DOM upon page load. BeautifulSoup doesn't recognize this?

Comment: Could I uncomment out that code block using regular expressions or something?

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the table you've identified. You'll need to download chromedriver.exe into your directory or provide the correct path to it.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

year = 2021
team = "NYK"
team_url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{team}/{year}.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

driver.get(team_url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tbl = soup.find('table', {'id': 'team_misc'})
print(tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the table you are looking for is placed inside an `HTML comment`, a possible solution would be to parse these elements, and return when it finds the matching `id`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment #import the Comment object

year = 2021
team = "NYK"
team_url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{team}/{year}.html"
html = urlopen(team_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
for c in comments:
    ele = BeautifulSoup(c.strip(), 'html.parser')
    if tbl := ele.find("table"):
        if (tbl_id := tbl.get("id")) == "team_misc":
            print(tbl)
```